# Xcode how to symbolicate emailed .ips.beta file from app using TestFlight

Tags: ios, xcode, crash-reports, symbolicate

how can I symbolicate a .ips.beta file that is emailed to me from my test users who generate the file from /settings/privacy/analytics/analytics data/myapp...

trying to simply find out the line of code that is causing the crash.

I am using TestFlight at the moment to distribute the app and using Xcode 9/ios 11

Comment: You need the symbols file (dSYM) that was generated with the build.  It's not included in the IPA.

Comment: How can I get that file from a TestFlight user?